# How can I find a standard method of predicting next values of a stock market using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Thank you for reading. I'm not good at English.

I am wondering how to predict and get future time series data after model training. I would like to get the values after N steps.

I wonder if the time series data has been properly learned and predicted.

How i do this right get the following (next) value?

I want to get the next value using like model.predict or etc

I have `x_test` and `x_test[-1] == t`, so the meaning of the next value is `t+1, t+2, .... t+n,`

In this example I want to get predictions of the next `t+1, t+2 ... t+n`

---

## First

I tried using stock index data

```
inputs = total_data[len(total_data) - forecast - look_back:]
inputs = scaler.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(look_back, inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i - look_back:i])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

but the result is like below

[image]

The results from `X_test[-20:]` and the following 20 predictions looks like same.

I'm wondering if it's the correct train and predicted value.

I'm wondering if it was a right training and predict.

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/2e1759a0e435ff95b7a017e301db634f)

The method I tried first did not work correctly.

---

## Seconds

I realized something is wrong, I tried using another official data

So, I used the time series in the Tensorflow tutorial to practice predicting the model.

```
a = y_val[-look_back:] 
for i in range(N-step prediction):                             # predict a new value n times.
    tmp = model.predict(a.reshape(-1, look_back, num_feature)) # predicted value     
    a = a[1:]                                                  # remove first     
    a = np.append(a, tmp)                                      # insert predicted value
```

The results were predicted in a linear regression shape very differently from the real data.

[image: 2]

Output a linear regression that is independent of the real data:

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/96e0ba8d8c251046e89eae4bc5d40510)  (After the 25th line is my code.)

I'm really very curious what is a standard method of predicting next values of a stock market.

Thank you for reading the long question. I seek advice about your priceless opinion.

Comment: Just a tip before you invest too much time into this: The stock market can't be predicted using ML, many have tried this and many failed. It is highly dependent on global events, which can't be predicted and therefore can't be modelled either.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How can I find a standard method of predicting next values of a stock market...?"*

First - salutes to C64 practitioner!

Next, let me say, there is **no standard method** - there cannot be ***( one )***.

Principally - let me draw from your field of a shared experience - one can easily predict the near future flow of **laminar fluids** ( a technically "working" market instrument - is a model A, for which one can derive a better or worse predictive tool )

That will never work, however, for **turbulent states of the fluids** ( just read the complexity of the attempts to formulate the many-dimensional high-order PDE for a turbulence ( and it still just approximates the turbulence ) ) -- and this is the fundamentally "working" market ( after some expected fundamental factor was released ( read NFP or CPI ) or some flash-news was announced in the news - ( read a Swiss release of currency-bonding of CHF to some USD parity or Cyprus one time state tax on all speculative deposits ... the financial Big Bangs follow ... )

So, please, do not expect one, the less any simple, model for reasonably precise predictions, working for both the laminar and turbulent fluidics - the real world is for sure way more complex than this :o)